# Where should I put my question about Amazon affiliation?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I've been wanting to post a question regarding the Amazon Associates program, but I'm not sure what Stack Exchange site it would be most appropriate on.

So, well, I guess that's my question.  On what Stack Exchange site, if any, can I ask a question related to the Amazon affiliation program?

Comment: I can't say without knowing more -- 1) what is your job title relative to this question (webmaster? end user? site owner? programmer? sysadmin?) and 2) what are the specifics of your question?

Comment: I'm thinking about using it on my blog, so not really programming-related (hence my question here).  The question itself is if I should use the .com or .co.uk amazon site (as I'm located in Europe but most of my visitors are US-based).  BTW: Hi Jeff :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on your update in the comments

> I'm thinking about using it on my blog, so not really programming-related (hence my question here). The question itself is if I should use the .com or .co.uk amazon site (as I'm located in Europe but most of my visitors are US-based)

I'd say https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ -- webapps is end user focused, not really focused on people who manage a website and make decisions like this about content that is being posted to the website.

It wouldn't be *terrible* on webapps, it could work there, but the "webmaster" vs. "end user" distinction is what matters here. So I suspect you'll get much, much better answers from "people who run websites" than "people who use GMail and Facebook".

And in the future, you can always check

https://stackexchange.com/sites to see what sites we have, and what the audience is for each one.

Comment: +1 The closest match is def. webmasters. As a mod there I can attest that questions regarding generating revenue through advertising and link exchange, etc, are acceptable there.

Comment: Thanks for that /sites link, quite interesting!  I wasn't aware of its existence until now.

Answer (score 0):

How about https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ ?